# view all table field value without while loop in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

View all table field values using `while` loop, but same value is repeated many times.

How to solve it...??
Please any one help me?

```
$tender_select_query ="SELECT * FROM new_tender_one,new_tender_two,new_tender_three,new_tender_four WHERE new_tender_one.id = new_tender_two.tender_id AND new_tender_one.id = new_tender_three.tender_id AND new_tender_one.id = new_tender_four.tender_id";
$tender_select_result =mysql_query($tender_select_query);
while($tender_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($tender_select_result)){
    $id =$tender_row['id'];
    $work_name =$tender_row['work_name'];
    $procuring_entity =$tender_row['procuring_entity'];
    $reference_no =$tender_row['reference_no'];
    $procurement_method =$tender_row['procurement_method'];
    $bid_eligibility =$tender_row['bid_eligibility'];
    $last_date =$tender_row['last_date'];
    $pre_tend_info =$tender_row['pre_tend_info'];
    $comp_work =$tender_row['comp_work'];
    $tend_security =$tender_row['tend_security'];
    $tend_instruction =$tender_row['tend_instruction'];
    $tend_invite =$tender_row['tend_invite'];
    $cont_details =$tender_row['cont_details'];
    $publish_date =$tender_row['publish_date'];
    $tender_status =$tender_row['tender_status'];

    $tender_id =$tender_row['tender_id'];
    $tender_type =$tender_row['tender_type'];
    $tender_type_subcat =$tender_row['tender_type_subcat'];

    $item_name =$tender_row['item_name'];
    $item_description =$tender_row['item_description'];
    $item_offer =$tender_row['item_offer'];
    $quantity =$tender_row['quantity'];
    $unit_type =$tender_row['unit_type'];

    $required_name =$tender_row['required_name'];
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `query` you used.

If you have the same `tender_id` in `new_tender_one` or `new_tender_two` or so on, you will get multiple rows for sure.

**`new_tender_one`**

```
id  | tender_title
1   | tender_1
2   | tender_2
```

**`new_tender_two`**

```
tender_id | tenderer_name
    1     |  smith
    1     |  john
    2     |  paul
```

**`result`**

```
id  | tender_title | tender_id | tenderer_name
1   | tender_1     |     1     |  smith
1   | tender_1     |     1     |  john
2   | tender_2     |     2     |  paul
```

Make sure don't have repeating `tender_id`s in tables `new_tender_two`,`new_tender_three`,`new_tender_four`.

If there is, you have to use sub queries. Then you need to know which `record` you need from those other `tables`. (Eg: for `id 1` whether `smith` or `john`).